# Sentence detection and extraction into same data frame

Tags: regex, r

I have a following data frame:

```
reviews <- data.frame(value = c("Product was received in excellent condition. Made with high quality materials. Very Good product",
                               "Inexpensive. An improvement over integrated graphics.",
                               "I love that product so excite. I will order again if I need more .",
                               "Excellent card, great graphics."),
                      user = c(1,2,3,4),
                      Review_Id = c("101968","101968","210546","112546"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and I need to have desired output:

```
        user     review_Id                                 sentence
           1        101968        Made with high quality materials.
           1        101968                        Very Good product
           2        101968                             Inexpensive.
           2        101968 An improvement over integrated graphics.
           3        210546           I love that product so excite.
           3        210546      I will order again if I need more .
           4        112546          Excellent card, great graphics.
```

I was wondering about something like this: `sent_detect(reviews$value)`

But how could I combine that function to have that desired output.

Comment: Are your data really this clean? (For example, do all sentences end in a full stop and are followed by a space?)

Comment: if not, you can try to use [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/openNLP/docs/Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator), there is an example at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data really are so tidy, you can just use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(reviews, "value", ".", direction = "long")
#                                          value user Review_Id
# 1: Product was received in excellent condition    1    101968
# 2:            Made with high quality materials    1    101968
# 3:                           Very Good product    1    101968
# 4:                                 Inexpensive    2    101968
# 5:     An improvement over integrated graphics    2    101968
# 6:               I love that product so excite    3    210546
# 7:           I will order again if I need more    3    210546
# 8:              Excellent card, great graphics    4    112546
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... this function is really amazing. It solves my task. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: And the last question... if I have end of sentence not only . but eg ! or ?, so how could I add that into sSplit function?

Comment: @martinkabe, you can try something like `cSplit(reviews, "value", "[.!?]", fixed = FALSE, stripWhite = FALSE, direction = "long")` to split on ".", "!", and "?".